# How to convert c++ for loop to Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I wrote a code in C++ and would like to convert it to Python3. How to do that?

```
int N = 1000
for (p=2; p*p<=N; p++)
    for (w=p*p; w<=N; w=w+p)
```

I tried to change the first for loop to:

```
for p in range(2,N**0.5+1):
```

But it doesn't work - *TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer*

And what about the second for loop?

Comment: try converting it to int.. like `int(N**0.5)`

Comment: `range(2,int(N**0.5+1)):` to be accurate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Try This ( in python You should do that with while ):</strike>

```
N = 1000
p = 2

while p*p <= N:

    p = p + 1
    w = p*p
    print(p)

    while w <= N:
        w = w + p
        print(w)
```

**UPDATE :**

The reason that you get the error "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" is that the "range" function expects "integers" as arguments, whereas "N ** 0.5" is of type float, so is "N ** 0.5+1". To resolve this issue you can simply use "int" function to the conversion from float to integer. The following code is what you are looking for:

```
N = 1000
for p in range(2, int(N ** 0.5) + 1, 1):
    for w in range(p * p, N + 1, p):
        print(p, w)
```

Comment: `p = p + 1` => `p += 1` and `w = w + p` => `w += p`

Comment: Is it possible to write `for(w=p*p; w<=N; w=w+p)` as a for loop in Python?

Comment: This while loop is not exactly the same as the loop in my question, it has one more execution so I have an error _list assignment index out of range_

Comment: The first p and w in this variant are effectively 3 and 9 instead of 2 and 4. Either increment p after the inner while loop or start p at 1 before the outer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int N = 1000
for (p=2; p*p<=N; p++)
    for (w=p*p; w<=N; w=w+p)
```

In Python, the `range()` function takes in 3 parameters: `int start`, `int stop`, `int step`. Since your second argument is `N**0.5`, with 0.5 of type float, the result of that calculation is interpreted as of type float.

My suggestion is:

```
from math import sqrt
n = 1000
m = int(sqrt(n))
for p in range(2,m):
  for w in range(p*p, n+1, p)
    print(p,w)
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Nice! so you basically copied  my answer and replaced "**0.5" with the "sqrt" function? which also needs importing the "math" module unnecessarily (import math can be avoided if you simply use "**0.5"). Could you please elaborate apart from using the sqrt function instead of "**0.5" how your answer is different from mine?

Comment: @DRPK This problem is not that difficult, I don't have the comment privilege at the time and wanted to explain it a little bit more, didn't mean to copy you in any way

Comment: It's almost the same as DRPK answer. You forgot `m+1` and a colon in the 2nd for loop.